# React redux: IntlProvider - Can't resolve 'react-intl-redux' typescript

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-intl

I need to have multi language app. I use default template which is created via Visual studio react-redux project. When I use `<IntlProvider locale="en">` in my render function, it throws me an error during compiling. I checked `node_modules` and there is `react-intl-redux` folder in `node_modules/@types` folder.

ERROR in ./ClientApp/boot-client.tsx

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-intl-redux' in 'C:\Projects\C3PO.Admin\AdminConsole.Web\ClientApp'

@ ./ClientApp/boot-client.tsx 15:0-48

@ multi react-hot-loader/patch event-source-polyfill webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=__webpack_hmr&dynamicPublicPath=true ./ClientApp/boot-client.tsx

Here is my `boot-client.tsx` file

```
import './css/site.css';
import 'bootstrap';
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import configureStore from './configureStore';
import { ApplicationState }  from './store';
import * as RoutesModule from './routes';
import { HashRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import "@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css";
import "@progress/kendo-ui";
let routes = RoutesModule.routes;
import { IntlProvider } from "react-intl-redux";

// Create browser history to use in the Redux store
const baseUrl = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].getAttribute('href')!;
const history = createBrowserHistory({ basename: baseUrl });

// Get the application-wide store instance, prepopulating with state from the server where available.
const initialState = (window as any).initialReduxState as ApplicationState;
const store = configureStore(history, initialState);

function renderApp() {
    // This code starts up the React app when it runs in a browser. It sets up the routing configuration
    // and injects the app into a DOM element.
    ReactDOM.render(
        <AppContainer>
            <Provider store={store}>
                <IntlProvider locale="en">
                    <ConnectedRouter history={history} children={routes} />
                </IntlProvider>
            </Provider>
        </AppContainer>,
        document.getElementById('react-app')
    );
}

renderApp();

// Allow Hot Module Replacement
if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./routes', () => {
        routes = require<typeof RoutesModule>('./routes').routes;
        renderApp();
    });
}
```

Here is my `webpack.config` file

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;
const merge = require('webpack-merge');

module.exports = (env) => {
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);

    // Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
    const sharedConfig = () => ({
        stats: { modules: false },
        resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'] },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: 'dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.tsx?$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: 'awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true' },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [new CheckerPlugin()]
    });

    // Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
    const clientBundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';
    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig(), {
        entry: { 'main-client': './ClientApp/boot-client.tsx' },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.css$/, use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ use: isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' }) }
            ]
        },
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, clientBundleOutputDir) },
        plugins: [
            new ExtractTextPlugin('site.css'),
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            // Plugins that apply in development builds only
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(clientBundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
            // Plugins that apply in production builds only
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
        ])
    });

    // Configuration for server-side (prerendering) bundle suitable for running in Node
    const serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig(), {
        resolve: { mainFields: ['main'] },
        entry: { 'main-server': './ClientApp/boot-server.tsx' },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./ClientApp/dist/vendor-manifest.json'),
                sourceType: 'commonjs2',
                name: './vendor'
            })
        ],
        output: {
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
            path: path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp/dist')
        },
        target: 'node',
        devtool: 'inline-source-map'
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
};
```